# on press post the variables to database (react native)

Tags: reactjs, react-native

i have this

> POST api http://myIP/api/confirm

that post the name , text , service_name , office_name , date , time

and i want to use it to post this variables in react native

on press in botton post these variables and give me alert message 
how can i do this
here is my react native code

```
<View>
  <Text> {this.props.navigation.state.params.name}- {this.props.navigation.state.params.text} </Text>
  <Text> {this.props.navigation.state.params.service_name}</Text>
  <Text>{this.props.navigation.state.params.office_name}</Text>
  <Text>{this.props.navigation.state.params.date}</Text>
  <Text{this.props.navigation.state.params.time} </Text> 

  <Button rounded
     title='next'
     onPress={() => {
     Alert.alert('The Appointment booked') }} /> 
</View>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do the following

```
fetch("http://myIP/api/confirm", {
  method: "POST",
  headers: {
    Accept: "application/json",
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({
    firstParam: "yourValue",
    secondParam: "yourOtherValue"
  })
})
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(responseJson => {
    Alert.alert(
      "Alert Title",
      "My Alert Msg",
      [
        {
          text: "Cancel",
          onPress: () => console.log("Cancel Pressed"),
          style: "cancel"
        },
        { text: "OK", onPress: () => console.log("OK Pressed") }
      ],
      { cancelable: false }
    );
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.error(error);
  });
```

but please import the Alert from react-native